# upload static file with axios as formdata

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am looking to uplaod static file to server with  `axios` how can achieve this :

```
import pdf from "./sample.pdf"

const formData = new FormData()
formData.append("file",pdf)

await axios.post("upload",formData, {headers: {'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; 
boundary=${formData._boundary}`}})
```

also i tried to create new file with javascript `File()` construct like so :`const file = new File([pdf], name + '.pdf', {type: 'application/pdf'});`
but its turn out the file will be empty with unsupported type.

so how can i covert the static file to formData any help,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this how i did it: 
first i turn the imported file to base64 using this function:

```
   const data = await axios.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).then((response) => 
          {
      let pdf= btoa(new Uint8Array(response.data).reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), ''));
      return `data:${response.headers['content-type'].toLowerCase()};base64,${pdf}`;
    });
```

then convert the base64 to file object :

```
  function dataURLtoFile() {
      var arr = data.split(','),
        mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(arr[1]),
        n = bstr.length,
        u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

      while (n--) {
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
      }

      return new File([u8arr], name + '.pdf', {type: mime});
    }
```

and finally executed the 2 function to get result :

```
    const pdf = await dataURLtoFile();
    bodyFormData.append('pdf', pdf);
    await sendReport(bodyFormData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert pdf to base64 and then append it formData.

When you import a pdf file and do a console.log you will see the `url` (not file blob/data).

You can fetch the pdf file and in the `then` block, make a post request.

**Like this**

```js
import test from "./test.pdf";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
  console.log('test', test); //<---this prints just the url
    axios.get(test).then(pdf => {
      console.log(pdf.data);//<---this prints the base64

      const formdata = new FormData();
      formdata.append("pdf", pdf.data);
      formdata.append("name", "whatever");

      axios
        .post("", formdata, {
          headers: {
            "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
          }
        })
        .then(res => {});
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: yes but if i want to send it as file how to convert base64 to file object?